How do I extract substrings of a dataframe column by referencing another column?
Let's say I have a dataframe as below:
import pandas as pd

nhl_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "team": ["Tampa Bay Lightning", "Boston Bruins", "Toronto Maple Leafs",
             "Florida Panthers", "Detroit Red Wings"],
    "area": ["Tampa Bay", "Boston", "Toronto", "Florida", "Detroit"]})

Is there a way of comparing team column against area column to separate out the team and get a teamname column? (Lightning, Bruins, Maple Leafs, Panthers, Red Wings)
The only thing I could think of was trying regex and then manually going through to see if the area name is two-words or one-word.

Regex would work. I don't think you would even need to check the length of the area name. What did you try?

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. You can [edit] to improve your question. I just did a few things for you :)

You can replace the contents of one column in another, for each row, with apply on axis=1:
nhl_df["teamname"] = nhl_df.apply(
    lambda row: row["team"].replace(row["area"], "").strip(), axis=1
)

                  team       area     teamname
0  Tampa Bay Lightning  Tampa Bay    Lightning
1        Boston Bruins     Boston       Bruins
2  Toronto Maple Leafs    Toronto  Maple Leafs
3     Florida Panthers    Florida     Panthers
4    Detroit Red Wings    Detroit    Red Wings


Thank you so much!! I did not think about this at all.

I'm not sure if you can vectorize row-wise string operations like this, so that means falling back to Python operations: for each row, remove prefix area from team then strip.
nhl_df.apply(
    lambda row: row['team'].removeprefix(row['area']).strip(),
    axis=1,
)

0      Lightning
1         Bruins
2    Maple Leafs
3       Panthers
4      Red Wings
dtype: object

Pandas provides .str.removeprefix(), but it only takes a scalar, not a Series.

Yes you can vectorize. f = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x.removeprefix(y).strip()) and then f(df["team"], df["area"])

@SomeDude : From the Numpy documentation "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

With vectorized solution:
f = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x.removeprefix(y).strip()) 
out = f(df["team"], df["area"])
print(out)

array(['Lightning', 'Bruins', 'Maple Leafs', 'Panthers', 'Red Wings'],
      dtype='<U11')


You can extract team name by removing area name from team column using .str.replace()
nhl_df['teamname'] = nhl_df['team'].str.replace(nhl_df['area'], '').str.strip()


That didn't work for me; I got all NaNs. What version of Pandas are you using?
